# RabbitMQ : Cannot connect to distant machine (RPC)

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I want to connect two machines using RabbitMQ, using the  Remote procedure call.
I have two machines, my local machine (address : 10.3.9.73) and a VM machine (address : 10.3.9.2) .
These adresses are pingable.
I run the client app in my VM machine using this code :

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost("10.3.9.73");
factory.setPort(5672);
connection = factory.newConnection();
channel = connection.createChannel();

replyQueueName = channel.queueDeclare().getQueue();
consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
channel.basicConsume(replyQueueName, true, consumer);
```

And the server app in my local machine using this code :

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost("localhost");
factory.setPort(5672);     
connection = factory.newConnection();
channel = connection.createChannel();
channel.queueDeclare(RPC_QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
channel.basicQos(1);
QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
channel.basicConsume(RPC_QUEUE_NAME, false, consumer);
System.out.println(" [x] Awaiting RPC requests");
```

The code of the client app  fails and shows this error:

```
"com.rabbitmq.client.AuthenticationFailureException: ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile."
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please put the logfile content.

I think that you should to configure your login and password :

```
Sudo cp /usr/share/doc/rabbitmq-server-[rabbitmq version]/rabbitmq.config.example /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
```

Then search for

```
%%{loopback_users, []}
```

And remove ‘%%’, Then restart rabbitmq server.

then you should add those following lines in your code:

```
factory.setUsername("guest");
factory.setPassword("guest");
```

by default, you can use guest as your login and password

if this doesn't work,
you should test if your client can connect to your server through the port 
5672

```
 telnet 10.3.9.73 5672
```